# R - Find a value based on a criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataframe DF in which I have numerous of columns, one is with Dates and an other is the Hour.
My point is that I need to find the PRICE (dame datafra 36 hours before. All my days don't have 24 hours so I can't just shift my data set.
My idea was to look for the day before in my dataset & 12 hours before.

This is what I wrote but this is not working:

```
for (i in 38:nrow(DF)){


RefDay=as.Date(DF$Date[i])
  HourRef=DF$Hour[i]


DF$P24[i]=DF[which(DF$Date == (RefDay-1))& which(DF$Hour == (HourRef-36)),"PRICE"]


}
```

Here is my DF:

```
'data.frame':   20895 obs. of  45 variables:
 $ Hour                           : Factor w/ 24 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Date                           : POSIXct, format: "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01" ...
 $ PRICE                          : num  29.4 24.7 23.4 21.9 20.2 ...
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
  DF.Hour    DF.Date DF.PRICE
1       0 2016-07-01    29.36
2       1 2016-07-01    24.69
3       2 2016-07-01    23.42
4       3 2016-07-01    21.91
5       4 2016-07-01    20.19
6       5 2016-07-01    22.44
```

Comment: can u little bit clear ...like on what filed u want to apply filter and what kind of output expecting

Comment: please post a sample of your data rather than just its structure

Comment: Sure.
For example, in the line of the 05/02/2018 hour 18 I want to add a value, the PRICE here which was 36 hours before, so the price of the 04/02/20018 at 6:00:00

I hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill the data.frame with full days. You can do it with complete in tidyr. It will fill the not existing values with NA. 
If you have any NAs in your full data.frame you can go for the 36th element before with for example lag(price, 36).

```
DF <- complete(DF, Hour, Date) %>% arrange(Date) 
DF$Price[is.na(DF$Price)] <- lag(Price, 36)
```